# Dispatch doesn't work properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, grand-central-dispatch, searchbar

I try to get some data in background and refresh a tableview when typing in  the search bar, there is my current code:

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        Games * game = [[Games alloc] init];
        NSArray * temp = [game comingSoonWithPlatform:@"pc" header:[game gameHeader] parseLink:[game gameComingSoonListLinkWithPlatform:@"pc"]];
        self.searchArray = [temp valueForKey:@"results"];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    });
}
```

What am I doing wrong? If I type one more word in the search bar or if I tap the cancel button, it is refreshing and  the data appear in tableview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From main thread you are creating background thread, and after doing any processing there you need to switch to main thread to update UI.

For example, you can do your coding stuff in below method as-

```
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    // [activityIndicator startAnimating];
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

        // do your background code here
        Games * game = [[Games alloc] init];
        NSArray * temp = [game comingSoonWithPlatform:@"pc" header:[game gameHeader] parseLink:[game gameComingSoonListLinkWithPlatform:@"pc"]];
        self.searchArray = [temp valueForKey:@"results"];

        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            // you are now on the main queue again, update ui here  
        //[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: You should put the `self.searchArray` assignment inside the dispatch to the main queue, too. (This is an object you're using from the main thread, so you shouldn't be changing it from a background thread. Synchronize your access, most easily achieved by simply putting this assignment inside the block you dispatch back to the main thread.) Also, there's no need for `dispatch_sync` here. A `dispatch_async` would be preferable.

Answer (score 2):

The call to `[self.tableView reloadData];` has to be on the main thread. Replace the line

```
[self.tableView reloadData];
```

with

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [self.tableView reloadData];
});
```